# How can I make VSCode focus on the active editor by hitting Escape?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This drives me nuts, I am so used to Visual Studio where I can hit Escape and get back to editing. VSCode doesn't do it! Ugh! Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Hit esc while doing what?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This was annoying me too, so I figured it out.
[Turns out they've got the command under the hood but not bound to any keys](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commit/7e580570322c5bfaffc07d98bd5d7320ef78f3ca)

1. Cmd+Shift+P
2. Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)
3. Add this object:

```
{
    "key": "escape",
    "command":"workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
    "when":"!editorTextFocus"
}
```

Comment: change `when` to `explorerViewletFocus` to avoid breaking a lot of default behaviors, like hitting esc inside the editor to close the find / replace tool

Comment: `!explorerViewletFocus` breaks vim shortcut `escape` to return to normal mode.